# How to convert Stanford Parser string output to data table format

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am experimenting with the Stanford NLP Parser in Python, calling Stanford tools from `nltk` module. I have already parsed a chunk of text, which is returned as a string in the following form:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP
        (NP (NNS MEPs))
        (PP (IN from) (PP (IN across) (NP (DT the) (NNP EU)))))
      (VP
        (VBP are)
        (VP
          (VBG organising)
          (S
            (VP
              (TO to)
              (VP
                (VB trigger)


[... continues ]
```

Now I need to represent these data into table format (e.g. a `numpy` array), so that I can run some ML model on it.

I want to feed some processed sequence of words into an RNN. I thought parsing information would be very useful for the understanding of the structure of the sentence, but I don't know how this is usually done. How parsing data are fed into language models?

How to do that?

Comment: For clarification, this is not a string but a nested tree representation. What sort of Model do you want to train on your data? Converting the tree into a list or numpy array is a simple recursive algorithm that you can make up yourself, but this won't help you since you need to determine what your model shall predict, i order to choose the layout of your input data.

Comment: I added an explanation in the main question, thanks

Comment: Parsing in general is the structure of the sentence. Apart from this there is some semantic structure, which can be reduced to dependencies between functions and arguments on string level (verb-object relations) or if you want to enrich your model with semantic data, can be extended to the usage of embeddings (vector representations of words in a high dimensional room). What shall your RNN predict?

Comment: I wish to try three different tasks: Language generation; Sentiment analysis; Stance detection. I know I might have to operationalize parsing data in different ways, I was just looking for hints on how to encapsualte those informations in a 2D numpy matrix

Comment: For sentiment analysis, I never used parsing output, but plain tokenized text as arrays and a net of bi-LSTM cells to feed in. Do you mean text generation in the sense of summarization?